# When -g should be used to print stack traces in OCaml ?

Tags: debugging, exception, compilation, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to get a stacktrace with `Printexc.get_backtrace`, but I'm getting an error:

`(Program not linked with -g, cannot print stack backtrace)`

I'm compiling like this:

`ocamlfind ocamlc -g -o foo ... $(FOO_OBJS)`

FOO_OBJS are compiled with just:
`ocamlc -c $OBJ`

What's wrong? Should every `.cmo` be compiled with `-g`?

If exception occurs in an object compiled without `-g` will I get a partial stacktrace, or no stacktrace at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What's wrong? Should every .cmo be compiled with -g?

Yes, you must add the `-g` option to compilation and linking. You can also use `ocamldebug` to step through the program with this option on. Also the enviroment variable, `OCAMLRUNPARAM` must be set to `b`.

> If exception occurs in an object compiled without -g will I get a
>   partial stacktrace, or no stacktrace at all?

You bet! I recall a few times that I'd forgotten the `-g` option and the back-trace was just of the standard library.

Comment: By the way all libraries (cma and cmxa) should be compiled with -g, otherwise the poor user gets incomplete stack backtraces.

Comment: You are lucky to get partial backtrace, sometimes mixing modules with and without -g makes backtraces completely wrong - see PR#5074

Comment: There is an `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b` environment variable you can set, how is that related?

Comment: Instead of specifying `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b` you can just add `let () = Printexc.record_backtrace = true` at the top of your unit test file before the call to `OUnit.run_test_tt`.  That way your compiled test binary is more self-contained.